# Can I stream query results using JDO?

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I want to export all Objects (rows) in my database. They don't fit into memory at once, so I want to stream them instead of fetching all at once. Which approach has a low memory footprint? Does JDO (Datanucleus implementaion) support streaming?

In another project I was able to do it using a jdbc ResultSet and a fetchsize of 100. However I'd like to use JDO's mapping if possible, rather than a plain JDBC implmenetation.

Edit: I forgot to say: I use a strong cache for the PersistenceManager, can I disable it? The data is readonly anyway, no need to keep it.

Edit: query code:

Service method that calls the Repository Method is annotated with Springs @Transactional(readonly=true)annotation, persistenceManagerFactory is a Spring proxy, try-catch-finally handling omitted, level1 cache as already said is strong:

```
public class MyRepository extends AbstractRepository<MyItem> {
    public Collection<MyItem> retrieve(Object value) {
        return query("myfiel==:myvalue",value)
    }
}

public class AbstractRepository<T> {
    private Class<T> type;
    private PersistenceManagerFactory persistenceManagerFactory;

    public Collection<T> query(String query, Object value) {
        return createManager().newQuery(type, query).execute(value);
    }

    public PersistenceManager createManager() {
        return persistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: define "streaming". you don't say what you want to do with the result List, or where any connection/transaction boundary is

Comment: I want to write each Object into a PrintStream. What is a connection/transaction boundary?

Comment: Post your query code and where you start/commit the transaction (assuming you do that).

Comment: added code. Transaction is readonly, and closed/comitted after writing into the PrintWriter. I think the main issue is the strong level1 cache, don't you? Or what do you have in mind?

Comment: any object brought into memory will be put in the L1 cache; so using "strong" would be unwise to say the least. Objects are only loaded when you access them in the query results

Comment: as far as I understood, I cannot change the l1 cache type per PM or query, correct? I have to change the whole system configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To conclude the comments: Impossible to solve with JDO and level1 cache = strong. I evaluate to use Spring JdbcTemplate for such queries.